# read values for a mongodb query from file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query all documents from a mongodb collection of which the criteria is inside a file.

**criteria-file.txt:**

```
value1
value2
value3
...
```

Currently I'm building the query like this

**built-test.js.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'db.collection.find({keyfield: {$in:[' > test.js
cat criteria-file.txt| while read i
do
    echo "\"$i\"," >> test.js
done
echo ']}})' >> test.js
```

The query document is way under 16MB in size, but I wonder if there's a better way which is more elegant and efficient, especially, because over time I will most probably be over 16MB for the query document. I'm eager to get your suggestions.

BTW, I was wondering, for those 25K criteria values seeking in a collection with currently 200 million entries, the query time is only a bit over a minute and the CPU load doesn't seem to be too bad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file  into an array using the [cat()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cat/) native shell method. Then, loop over the array of criteria values to *find* the matching documents and store all the documents in an array; this will be your list of matches.

```
var criteria_file = cat("criteria-file.txt");
var criteria_array = criteria_file.split("\n");

var result_ids_arr = [ ];

for (let value of criteria_array) {

    let id_arr = db.collection.find( { keyfield: value }, { _id: 1} ).toArray();
    result_ids_arr = result_ids_arr.concat(id_arr);
}
```

The result array of the `_id` values, e.g.: `[ { "_id" : 11 }, { "_id" : 34 }, ... ]`

All this JavaScript can be run from the command prompt or the *mongo shell*, using the [load()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very much what I was looking for. Plus, this method reduced my 25K criteria query from over a minute to 35 seconds. Great!!

Comment: I have another use case with a criteria file of 27 Millioin records and then cat says: `2019-11-25T18:59:37.568+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: cat() : file to big to load as a variable : @(shell):1:8` ... I guess now Joe Drumgoole's answer will kick in: Divide and conquer.

Comment: Linux has options to divide a file in various ways; chunks, size, number of lines, etc. Browsing thru I found this: [how to split large files](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/split-large-text-file-smaller-files-linux/).  Additionally, you can also do some research on the topic "programming with very large files", in case the process needs to be run often and be automated.

Answer (score 1):

Split the criteria file into different chunks ensuring that the chunks don't exceed 16MB.

Run the same query on each chunk only now you can run the queries in parallel.

if you want to get extra fancy you can use the aggregation pipeline to do a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) query and send all the output results from each query to a single results collection using `$merge`[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/).